# Calling a Partial View and passing multiple ViewBag values as parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I have the following

```
public ActionResult Index()    
{
 ViewBag.Stage1="Module1";
 ViewBag.Stage2="Module2";
 ....
}
```

Now within View I am calling a partial View and passing ViewBag

```
@Html.Partial("MyMenu", new ViewDataDictionary(new { Stage1= ViewBag.Stage1, Stage2= ViewBag.Stage2}))
```

But here I am getting error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Stage1'
I even tried using something like

```
@Html.Partial("_LeftMenu", new {Level1=ViewData["Level1"],Level2=ViewData["Level2"] })
```

The same thing continues here as well the thing is I need to pass two values and render some Html based on values in ViewBag. Thanks any help is highly appreciated. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to access the viewbag data within the partial view if you call `@Html.Partial("MyMenu")`. But this might not work if you also want to pass a model.

Comment: @elolos I am ain't passing any model except the ViewBag's as mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the Viewbag within the partial view without passing it through the @Html helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify your view code with this.

```
@Html.Partial("MyMenu", new ViewDataDictionary{{"Stage1", ViewBag.Stage1},{"Stage2", ViewBag.Stage2}})
```

Comment: I get an error saying Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference.

Comment: can u please share your partial view "MyMenu" code as same code working at my side.  In my "MyMenu" partial view i have only this code @{
    
    Response.Write("hello " + ViewData["Stage1"]);
}